# Apply a function list of columns in R

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe

I have a big data frame with hundreds of columns.
The date values have imported as a string.
So I fix them with:

```
df$col1 <- as.POSIXct(strptime(df$col1, "%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S"))
```

but rather than copy and pasting this 10 times for each date column is it possible to just supply a list of columns

```
date_cols <- c(cols, col2, col3, col4)
```

and apply the function to all 4 columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the selected columns in 'date_cols' object and convert to `POSIXct` class by specifying the 'format'.  The output will be a `list` which can be assigned back to the original columns.

```
df[date_cols] <- lapply(df[date_cols], as.POSIXct, format= "%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")
```

where

```
date_cols <- paste0('col', 1:4)
```

---

Or this can be done using the `mutate_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
          mutate_each_(funs(as.POSIXct(., format="%d%b%y:%H:%M:%S")), date_cols)
df
#                col1                col2                col3
#1 2002-08-03 03:05:20 2003-01-12 06:02:22 2002-01-03 03:05:20
#2 2005-09-05 04:02:25 2005-01-05 10:20:25 2005-08-05 04:02:25
#                 col4       col5
#1 2003-02-12 06:02:22 -0.5458808
#2 2005-11-05 10:20:25  0.5365853
```

NOTE: If we use `%<>%` from `library(magrittr)` in place of `%>%`, we don't need to assign the output back to the original dataset.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(col1=c('03Aug02:03:05:20', '05Sep05:04:02:25'), 
     col2= c('12Jan03:06:02:22', '05Jan05:10:20:25'), 
     col3=c('03Jan02:03:05:20', '05Aug05:04:02:25'),
     col4= c('12Feb03:06:02:22', '05Nov05:10:20:25'), 
     col5=rnorm(2))
```